# RadiAnt: how to connect PACS system?

Tags: radiant

I am using `RadiAnt`, and `Orthanc` as the `PACS` system. I want to connect `RadiAnt` with `Orthanc`.

The configuration UI is:

[image]

The `Orthanc` is Ok for my computer. And I have uploaded one patient to `Orthanc`:

[image]

However, in the `RadiAnt`, I cannot find any patient:

[image]

Is there any thing wrong with my process?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the solution. The key point is to edit the Orthanc configure file.

For `Orthanc Server/Configuration/orthanc.json` file, the modified part is:

[image]

Then, restart the computer, and click the `search` file, I can find the Orthanc uploaded patient:

[image]

Hope it can help somebody.